# How to determine a function from outputs

Tags: functions, interpolation, data-analysis

Given the following inputs and outputs to a function, how would I determine an algorithm to fit?

```
f( 1 ) = 1
f( 2 ) = 2
f( 3 ) = 3
f( 4 ) = 2
f( 5 ) = 4
f( 6 ) = 6
f( 7 ) = 3
f( 8 ) = 4
f( 9 ) = 14
f( 10 ) = 9
f( 11 ) = 18
f( 12 ) = 12
f( 13 ) = 12
f( 14 ) = 42
f( 15 ) = 15
f( 16 ) = 4
f( 17 ) = 24
f( 18 ) = 40
f( 19 ) = 60
f( 20 ) = 51
f( 21 ) = 24
f( 22 ) = 30
f( 23 ) = 130
f( 24 ) = 90
f( 25 ) = 60
f( 26 ) = 72
f( 27 ) = 140
f( 28 ) = 42
f( 29 ) = 156
f( 30 ) = 48
f( 31 ) = 15
f( 32 ) = 12
f( 33 ) = 168
f( 34 ) = 48
f( 35 ) = 414
f( 36 ) = 483
f( 37 ) = 33
f( 38 ) = 36
f( 39 ) = 660
f( 40 ) = 39
f( 41 ) = 380
f( 42 ) = 672
f( 43 ) = 437
f( 44 ) = 364
f( 45 ) = 403
f( 46 ) = 315
f( 47 ) = 550
f( 48 ) = 48
f( 49 ) = 48
f( 50 ) = 369
f( 51 ) = 1950
f( 52 ) = 481
f( 53 ) = 280
f( 54 ) = 180
f( 55 ) = 90
f( 56 ) = 56
f( 57 ) = 144
f( 58 ) = 756
f( 59 ) = 252
f( 60 ) = 4278
f( 61 ) = 4350
f( 62 ) = 816
f( 63 ) = 105
f( 64 ) = 12
f( 65 ) = 432
f( 66 ) = 98
f( 67 ) = 120
f( 68 ) = 1924
f( 69 ) = 186
f( 70 ) = 64
f( 71 ) = 8736
f( 72 ) = 4004
f( 73 ) = 351
f( 74 ) = 552
f( 75 ) = 32604
f( 76 ) = 720
f( 77 ) = 77
f( 78 ) = 496
f( 79 ) = 16740
f( 80 ) = 6783
f( 81 ) = 130
f( 82 ) = 72
f( 83 ) = 1680
f( 84 ) = 330
f( 85 ) = 228
f( 86 ) = 152
f( 87 ) = 87
f( 88 ) = 240
f( 89 ) = 711
f( 90 ) = 6930
f( 91 ) = 1344
f( 92 ) = 1947
f( 93 ) = 495
f( 94 ) = 1680
f( 95 ) = 30240
f( 96 ) = 96
f( 97 ) = 25200
f( 98 ) = 24486
f( 99 ) = 22440
f( 100 ) = 540
f( 101 ) = 1566
f( 102 ) = 279
f( 103 ) = 24024
f( 104 ) = 5040
f( 105 ) = 1197
f( 106 ) = 336
f( 107 ) = 48450
f( 108 ) = 707
f( 109 ) = 153972
f( 110 ) = 3009
f( 111 ) = 1958
f( 112 ) = 3068
f( 113 ) = 2366298
f( 114 ) = 37240
f( 115 ) = 5628
f( 116 ) = 1674
f( 117 ) = 4635
f( 118 ) = 34099
f( 119 ) = 40194
f( 120 ) = 48300
f( 121 ) = 43680
f( 122 ) = 13992
f( 123 ) = 2568
f( 124 ) = 4368
f( 125 ) = 234
f( 126 ) = 1680
f( 127 ) = 105
f( 128 ) = 24
f( 129 ) = 5320
f( 130 ) = 4664
f( 131 ) = 8760
f( 132 ) = 145860
f( 133 ) = 1361122
f( 134 ) = 630
f( 135 ) = 12078
f( 136 ) = 135
f( 137 ) = 17160
f( 138 ) = 445536
f( 139 ) = 6612
f( 140 ) = 15960
f( 141 ) = 99540
f( 142 ) = 34632
f( 143 ) = 14430
f( 144 ) = 57810
f( 145 ) = 39240
f( 146 ) = 24252
f( 147 ) = 1008
f( 148 ) = 144
f( 149 ) = 54054
f( 150 ) = 171380
f( 151 ) = 3444
f( 152 ) = 37076
f( 153 ) = 1320
f( 154 ) = 1188810
f( 155 ) = 3013
f( 156 ) = 91560
f( 157 ) = 239666
f( 158 ) = 720720
f( 159 ) = 11589240
f( 160 ) = 1260
f( 161 ) = 264040
f( 162 ) = 294
f( 163 ) = 1740
f( 164 ) = 16170
f( 165 ) = 67284
f( 166 ) = 162
f( 167 ) = 1560
f( 168 ) = 9798
f( 169 ) = 74542
f( 170 ) = 62118
f( 171 ) = 508164
f( 172 ) = 578952
f( 173 ) = 156
f( 174 ) = 85470
f( 175 ) = 636
f( 176 ) = 2880
f( 177 ) = 6120
f( 178 ) = 1890
f( 179 ) = 98640
f( 180 ) = 329448
f( 181 ) = 1452990
f( 182 ) = 39480
f( 183 ) = 1833
f( 184 ) = 43000
f( 185 ) = 28210
f( 186 ) = 51414
f( 187 ) = 1358708
f( 188 ) = 4218
f( 189 ) = 83754
f( 190 ) = 146160
f( 191 ) = 9090
f( 192 ) = 870
f( 193 ) = 340
f( 194 ) = 168
f( 195 ) = 1979040
f( 196 ) = 251940
f( 197 ) = 168
f( 198 ) = 6020
f( 199 ) = 28200
f( 200 ) = 9006
f( 201 ) = 388
f( 202 ) = 3817632
f( 203 ) = 9975
f( 204 ) = 360
f( 205 ) = 35784
f( 206 ) = 9490
f( 207 ) = 1260
f( 208 ) = 138
f( 209 ) = 1911
f( 210 ) = 337554
f( 211 ) = 166152
f( 212 ) = 375648
f( 213 ) = 7182
f( 214 ) = 81788
f( 215 ) = 2604
f( 216 ) = 40455
f( 217 ) = 42432
f( 218 ) = 1115180
f( 219 ) = 406980
f( 220 ) = 85680
f( 221 ) = 8484
f( 222 ) = 10440
f( 223 ) = 5910
f( 224 ) = 12390
f( 225 ) = 224
f( 226 ) = 2520
f( 227 ) = 420420
f( 228 ) = 159120
f( 229 ) = 27192
f( 230 ) = 128520
f( 231 ) = 15660
f( 232 ) = 2772
f( 233 ) = 13095
f( 234 ) = 286440
f( 235 ) = 1789320
f( 236 ) = 175140
f( 237 ) = 8810490
f( 238 ) = 185650
f( 239 ) = 78672
f( 240 ) = 2055648
f( 241 ) = 3480
f( 242 ) = 27612420
f( 243 ) = 990
f( 244 ) = 21240
f( 245 ) = 769860
f( 246 ) = 4140
f( 247 ) = 63756
f( 248 ) = 28890
f( 249 ) = 3420
f( 250 ) = 11704
f( 251 ) = 1014600
f( 252 ) = 16560
f( 253 ) = 1226160
f( 254 ) = 55440
f( 255 ) = 315
f( 256 ) = 24
```

It's been a while since I've had to do it, but I recall a process for building polynomial functions based on input & output.  I would appreciate help in remembering the process, and I would also be interested to know if there are any tools to help.

Comment: Even though this is not homework, you should provide us with what you have so it becomes easier for people to understand your level and also allows them to answer the question well so you can understand it.

Comment: You can always create a discrete function. Like this: $$f(x) = \matrix{1 & & ; x = 1\\2 & & ; x = 2\\ \vdots}$$

Comment: Look up interpolation and curve fitting.

Comment: Interpolation might be what I was remembering from college, but I'm not sure it's actually what I need.  It seems to be more for calculating missing data in-between existing data points. I'm looking into GNU Octive as a possible tool to help me solve this.

Comment: Is there any context for the data. Curve fitting usually relies on understanding the physics behind the data otherwise there are just too many things you can do with a data. It is always possible to fit order n-1 polynomial to a sample with n data points, but I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Where is the data from?  It looks way to noisy for any fit to be useful.  If it is a puzzle, it may depend on how the numbers are written.  Otherwise, it looks like some sort of Collatz type sequence.

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to look at the simple $XY$ plot of the data:

[image: plot1]

Whoa. What if we take the logarithm of $Y$?

[image: logplot]

This looks like a power of $X$ with **a lot** of noise. Averaging the ratio of $\ln\ln Y/\ln X$ gives $0.42$. Indeed, $\ln Y\approx X^{0.42}$ is a reasonable "smoothed" approximation.

[image: power]

But I don't think that curve-fitting is the way to go here. The nature of the function, and the fact that the argument runs from $1$ to $256$ suggest that some binary operations might be involved. And look, we have  spikes at

```
113 = 0b01110001
159 = 0b10011111
242 = 0b11110010
```

Actually, I suspect we should subtract $1$ from $X$ to make it run from $0$ to $255$. Then these three spikes are at

```
112 = 0b01110000
158 = 0b10011110
241 = 0b11110001
```

Must be something about these chains of 0s and 1s.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm that you remember may be this, but I doubt if it is going to perform well on this data...

Consider the polynomial $\mathrm{shriek}(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3) \cdots (x-256)$ and define the family of polynomials
    $g_i(x) = \frac{\mathrm{shriek}(x)}{x-i}$ for $i = 1, \ldots, 256$.
$\mathrm{Shriek}(x)$ has $256$ terms and $(x-i)$ is one of them for every value of $i$ from $1$ to $256$ so $g_i(x)$ has $255$ terms.

$g_i(x)$ has the useful property that $g_i(x)$ is zero for every value of $x$ in $[1, 256]$ except $x=i$ and $g_i(i)$ is non-zero. In fact, it is a very large number.

For this reason, it's sensible to further define $h_i(x) = \frac{g_i(x)}{g_i(i)}$ so that $h_i(x)$ is now $0$ everywhere in $[1,256]$ except at $x=i$ and $h_i(i)$ is $1$.

We can now use this useful basis to construct a polynomial that fits your function $f(x)$...

$$F(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{256} (f(i) h_i(x))$$

As others have pointed out, there is a great deal of structure in your data and the polynomial $F(x)$ may not simplify to something succinct that captures the structure.

**Codicil**

I tried it with Mathematica on my Raspberry Pi ...

```
f[ 1 ] = 1; f[ 2 ] = 2; f[ 3 ] = 3; f[ 4 ] = 2; f[ 5 ] = 4; f[ 6 ] = 6; f[ 7 ] = 3; f[ 8 ] = 4
f[ 9 ] = 14; f[ 10 ] = 9; f[ 11 ] = 18; f[ 12 ] = 12; f[ 13 ] = 12; f[ 14 ] = 42; f[ 15 ] = 15; f[ 16 ] = 4
...
f[ 249 ] = 3420; f[ 250 ] = 11704; f[ 251 ] = 1014600; f[ 252 ] = 16560; f[ 253 ] = 1226160; f[ 254 ] = 55440; f[ 255 ] = 315; f[ 256 ] = 24; 

g[i_,x_] := Product[ If[i==j,1,(x-j)],{j,256}]

h[i_,x_] := g[i,x]/g[i,i]

F[x_] := Sum[ f[i] h[i,x], {i,256} ]

Simplify[F[x]]
```

Unsurprisingly, it produces something horrendous

Comment: Welcome to math.SX! Read [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) about writing mathematics.